# Ajax returning information but redirecting to a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to build a search utility in Laravel 4 with ajax where a user can search through various things such as orders and estimates and have the result(s) load as links to those orders, estimates, etc in the "search_results" div on the hope page.

Right now I've gotten the ajax to correctly go into the database and return the relevant information but instead of displaying it in the "search_results" div on the "home" route I'm redirected to the "search" route where the information is displayed where EVERYTHING of these orders are shown.

If anyone can point out why I'm being redirected to a different page instead of having the info load in the correct div on the home page or how to control what get's returned by ajax it would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my View:

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
{{Form::open( array('route' => 'search', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'search_form'))}}      

        {{ Form::select('search_table',
                array(
                    'select'        => 'Search...',
                    'commissions'   => 'Search commissions',
                    'estimates'     => 'Search estimates',
                    'orders'        => 'Search orders',
                    'warranties'    => 'Search warranties',
        ), null, array('id' => 'search_table')) }}

        <div class="search_box" id="search_column_div">
            <select id='search_column' name='search_column'>
                         <option value='created_at'>by date created</option>
                    </select>
        </div>

        <div id="search_input_div">
            <input id='search_input' name='search_input' class='search_input' placeholder='Enter Order Name'/>
        </div>

{{ Form::submit('Search', array('id' => 'search_button','class' => 'button expand radius search_button no_display'))}}


{{ Form::close() }}

   <div id="search_results">
   </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
/*AJAX Search*/


$(document).load(function(){
 $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#search_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#search_results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(thrownError);
            alert('Somethin went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function searchPost(){
    $search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
    $search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
    $search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

    $search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
    echo json_encode($search);
    exit;
}
```

Route:

```
/*Search Page for Ajax*/
    Route::post('/search', array(
        'as'    => 'search',
        'uses'  => 'HomeController@searchPost'
    ));
```

Comment: change `json_encode($search)` to `echo json_encode($search)` dont forget the echo part.

Comment: is your controller still contains this code?

Comment: ok, if `/search` is returning this: `"[{"id":88,"created_by":8,"assigned_to":16,"order_name" ... "` then its mean's it is passing your post parameters correctly. anyway please also update your JS code on your post as of what you are currently using.

Comment: aah so you are now using `get` method. wait let me add something on my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that before. That was suggested earlier on and seemed to make sense as I'm not trying to actually create anything.

Comment: aah so you are now using the `get` method

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the return in your controller. When anything is returned from a route or controller in Laravel, it is sent back to the browser. Usually it's sent in the form of a page redirect or url. In this case you're sending it data which the browser is parsing and displaying.

To do an AJAX request in your case you need to echo out the search results instead of returning them. And don't have a return statement in the function at all. Whatever you print out is what will be returned to your AJAX request in the form of a string. You'll more than likely want to json_encode the search results so that you can then parse them on the front-end more easily which will allow you to display the results any way you like.

EDIT: The reason your're being sent to another page still is because you're triggering the form submission in javascript. You actually want to prevent that and handle it solely with the AJAX request. That form submission is triggering a normal browser handled HTTP request which is reloading the page.

Comment: But if I echo the results I get an array to string conversion error.

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when you try to echo an array. Like I suggested, you'll want to json_encode your results before you echo them. If you don't want json you can serialize the array before echoing it. Regardless, the echo function isn't the important part; what's important is that you print what you want to return to the screen.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Any idea why I'm still getting redirected?

Comment: Did you remove the return statement at the end of the controller?

Comment: Yup, just have `$search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
  json_encode($search);
  print_r($search);` now

Comment: I did. I used print_r to print out $search in a more readable manner.

Comment: I thought I was handling it with the AJAX request. I deleted  $('form#search_form').submit(function(){ } but still have the same problem. How do I handle the submission via Ajax?

Comment: just run your `ajax` request outside your functions. unwrap your code first, wrap it back when your `ajax` request is working.

Comment: Just updated the post so you can see what I'm running, not sure if I missed anything or messed any part of it up.

Answer (score 1):

first is to test your /search page for json output for that you need to modify your code to:

```
    public function searchPost(){
        $search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
        $search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
        $search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

        $search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
        echo json_encode($search);
        exit;
    }
```

after this you should test your page e.g `www.webpage.com/main/search`
you should see a string with similar **format** to this:

```
{"player_id":1,"level":1,"quests":{"1":{"percent_completed":100,"quest_title":"the first quest"},"2":{"percent_completed":80,"quest_title":"the second quest"},"3":{"percent_completed":50,"quest_title":"the 3rd quest"}}}
```

### DEBUGGING

but since the function needs `post` data we will change your code to(temporarily):

```
public function searchPost(){
    //$search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
    //$search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
    //$search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

    //$search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
    $sample_array = array("id"=>1,"name"=>"sample");
    echo json_encode($sample_array);
    exit;
}
```

run your ajax on load:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#search_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#search_results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert('Somethin went wrong');
        }
    });
```

Comment: The result when I tried using exit in the controller is a blank screen on a different page. The snippet I put above was just to say that I expected to see a large string of information, sorry if I was being confusing.

Comment: did your `console.log("Success")` showed on your console before redirecting?

Comment: Nope, just some warning that some code in Jquery is deprecated.

Comment: aaah so you where not receiving an output from the searchPost() function from the start?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not even getting that "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http:.../search". message anymore.

Comment: @gv0029 follow my answer and check for output in `/search` page, you should see a bunch of string as a result, if you did see a `string` then your on the right track.

Comment: Yes I see {"id":1,"name":"sample"}

Comment: Sorry for a second I misread what you put and had to go back and fix it to get it to work.

Comment: so that means your `searchPost()` is working it might be on your `JS` side. my suggestion is change your `POST` to `GET` since your only passing parameters to retrive data and not using it to save data.

Comment: change `console.log("Success!")` to `console.log(data)` and you should see an `object` on your console. if you see that `object` then i think i may know the culprit.

Comment: Still getting redirected, still not seeing anything in console.

Comment: then you should run your $.ajax code on document load(not on click). let see if your page still does a reload.

Comment: Okay, interesting. When I had it run on load I immediately got the error message. Normally I just get redirected to the "search" route page. So that is something.

Comment: ok what did the error say? i hope that's not the `jquery is depreciated` part

Comment: Just the alert message from the " error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }" part

Comment: assuming you still have my code from above and you dont have that `print_r` stuff then you should be good. ajax post cant read `print_r`.
string"

Comment: Nope have everything like you put, when you said put my ajax on document load you meant like                  $(document).load(function(){
 $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#search_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#search_results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert('Somethin went wrong');
        }
    });
});    or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: instead of using `alert()` log those 3 parameters: `console.log(xhr); console.log(textStatus); console.log(thrownError);`

Comment: Still getting redirected, still getting the same "[{"id":88,"created_by":8,"assigned_to":16,"order_name" ... "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52639/discussion-between-viscocent-and-gv0029)